# Visual Studio 2019 is deadlock when I save a document

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

When I try to save a document in visual studio 2019, it deadlock. and then, I use dnspy attach to visual studio process, get the stacktrace here:

```
[托管到本机的转换]
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.NoMessagePumpSyncContext.Wait(System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout) (IL=epilog, Native=0x0C0CAC20+0x55)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.InvokeWaitMethodHelper(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext, System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout) (IL=epilog, Native=0x7B66D9A4+0x14)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(object obj, int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) (IL=epilog, Native=0x7B6742B0+0x18)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(object obj, int millisecondsTimeout) (IL=epilog, Native=0x7B6823F0+0xD)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (IL=???, Native=0x7B6FF390+0x219)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SpinThenBlockingWait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (IL≈0x0048, Native=0x7B6FD860+0xE9)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (IL≈0x007F, Native=0x7B760394+0x165)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (IL≈0x0019, Native=0x7B6FD780+0x36)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(System.TimeSpan timeout) (IL=epilog, Native=0x7B6FD718+0x55)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.WaitSynchronouslyCore(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (IL≈0x0015, Native=0x0C0D0830+0x69)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.WaitSynchronously(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (IL≈0x001F, Native=0x0C0D0770+0x74)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread() (IL=0x0126, Native=0x0C0CC180+0x346)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask<string>.CompleteOnCurrentThread() (IL≈0x0000, Native=0x0C0CD510+0x14)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run<string>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>> asyncMethod, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskCreationOptions creationOptions) (IL=epilog, Native=0x0C0CACC0+0x4F)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run<string>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>> asyncMethod) (IL=epilog, Native=0x0C0CAC80+0x39)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileChangeService.RunWithTracing<string>(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileChangeService.CompletionTracer tracer, System.Func<System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>> func) (IL=epilog, Native=0x0C7D1B80+0xBA)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileChangeService.IgnoreFile(uint cookie, string filename, bool ignore) (IL=epilog, Native=0x0C7C9530+0xB6)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileChangeService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsFileChangeEx.IgnoreFile(uint cookie, string filename, int fIgnore) (IL=0x001D, Native=0x2FDF2558+0x48)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextDocData.SuspendFileChangeNotification(string pszFilename, int fSuspend) (IL≈0x0065, Native=0x24FA4AE0+0xA2)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextDocData.BaseSave(string pszFilename, int fRemember) (IL=0x00F3, Native=0x24FA373C+0x1F9)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextDocData.Save(string pszFilename, int fRemember, uint nFormatIndex) (IL≈0x0015, Native=0x24FA363C+0x41)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextDocData.Save(string pszFileName, int fRemember) (IL=0x000A, Native=0x24FA39AC+0x10)
    [本机到托管的转换]
    [托管到本机的转换]
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.TextDocData.SaveDocData(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSSAVEFLAGS dwSave, out string pbstrMkDocumentNew, out int pfSaveCanceled) (IL=epilog, Native=0x24FA1754+0x37)
    [本机到托管的转换]
```

In another cases, I get the similar stacktrace too.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileChangeService.IgnoreFile
```

I want to know what this function is doing, and why it needs to lock something and wait.

Comment: Try disabling extensions/plugins and see if that affects your deadlock

Comment: thanks for your reply, I find the reason. the reason is visual assistx's cache folder. if it use the default directory, it will be placed in Extensions/random-dir/Data. but when I open some solution in same time, visual assist x will cache the symbol cache, it will cause the default cache directory changed. this will cause visual studio start Extensions changed process. it will start many tasks for this operation. so we can change the default symbol cache director for visual assistx, it will not dead lock now.

Comment: in this event processor, it will lock the critical section , which is used in this function.

Comment: this function is :ExtensionWatcher.OnExtensionsChangedAsync, when I debug visual studio by dnspy, I find this function. and the directory name is the cache folder of vax. so I find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply, I find the reason. the reason is visual assistx's cache folder. if it use the default directory, it will be placed in Extensions/random-dir/Data. but when I open some solution in same time, visual assist x will cache the symbol cache, it will cause the default cache directory changed. this will cause visual studio start Extensions changed process. it will start many tasks for this operation. so we can change the default symbol cache director for visual assistx, it will not dead lock now.
this function is :ExtensionWatcher.OnExtensionsChangedAsync, when I debug visual studio by dnspy, I find this function. and the directory name is the cache folder of vax. so I find this solution.